# How can I set alias in .zshrc file without it breaking ruby and/or chruby?

Tags: ruby, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, chruby, zsh-alias

I've been following the steps of this youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNQpDWLs4To) to make my terminal beautiful, which has involved installing iterm2, ohmyzsh, powerlevel10k, plugins for ohmyzsh (zsh-syntax-highlighting, zsh-autosuggestions) - these all work great. The final step is installing colorls using a ruby gem and setting an alias ls='colorls', this is where things have gone wrong. colorls is installed and the command works however when i try to set the alias and source the .zshrc file, restarting the terminal gives me warnings that my ruby install isn't found and that the alias isn't recognised.

For context, I don't have admin privileges to this machine (a mac) or permissions to  ~/Applications/ so I've been installing things to a new Applications folder in my account for example homebrew is in /Users/MY_USERNAME/Applications/homebrew/

Here is my .zshrc file:

```
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder
ZSH_CUSTOM=/Users/MYUSERNAME/.oh-my-zsh/custom

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=( 
    git
    zsh-autosuggestions
    chruby
    ruby
    macos
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias ls="colorls" 

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
source /Users/MYUSERNAME/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh

eval export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew";
export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/Cellar";
export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew";
export PATH="/Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/bin:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}";
export MANPATH="/Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:";
export INFOPATH="/Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
source /Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
chruby ruby-3.2.2

test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"
```

If I comment out 'alias ls="colorls"' i get no warnings and everything works great. If I leave it in, source ~/.zshrc, the alias works as expected. If I then restart the terminal I get the following output:

```
Last login: Wed Sep 20 13:33:59 on ttys001

[WARNING]: Console output during zsh initialization detected.

When using Powerlevel10k with instant prompt, console output during zsh
initialization may indicate issues.

You can:

  - Recommended: Change ~/.zshrc so that it does not perform console I/O
    after the instant prompt preamble. See the link below for details.

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly and prompt will update smoothly.

  - Suppress this warning either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

  - Disable instant prompt either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=off

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start slowly.

  - Do nothing.

    * You will see this error message every time you start zsh.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

For details, see:
https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#instant-prompt

-- console output produced during zsh initialization follows --

/Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh:5: command not found: colorls
chruby: unknown Ruby: ruby-3.2.2
```

Unsurprisingly running the ls command gives me `zsh: command not found: colorls`. I checked to see if chruby is working, from this I think chruby is fine but it can't find my non-system ruby install anymore

```
❯ chruby
❯ chruby -h
usage: chruby [RUBY|VERSION|system] [RUBYOPT...]
❯ chruby 3.2.2
chruby: unknown Ruby: 3.2.2
❯ cd /Users/MYUSERNAME/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2
```

In my troubleshooting searches online I've seen people asking about the gem environment, I don't know what to do with this but I can see it all uses the system ruby which I understand we don't want.

```
❯ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.10 (2022-04-12 patchlevel 210) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/MYUSERNAME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/MYUSERNAME/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-22
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/MYUSERNAME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/bin
     - /Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

The last thing I tried was to follow the advice in my .zshrc file **# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.** so I commented out the alias in there and I made this file /Users/MYUSERNAME/.oh-my-zsh/custom/my-aliases.zsh contaiing just the line `alias ls="colorls"` which should get sourced automatically. If I source ~/.zshrc my alias works, but then reopening the terminal gets me the same output as before `/Users/MYUSERNAME/Applications/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh:5: command not found: colorls chruby: unknown Ruby: ruby-3.2.2`

My understanding is that ruby and chruby and colorls are all installed and work but something happens when the terminal restarts and it forgets where some or all of these are?